# Disallow range of numeric URLs in robots.txt

Tags: apache, robots.txt

I want to disallow URLs with my robots txt with a url parameter and numeric order.
I have a website with GET parameters like:

```
example.com/show?id_item=1
```

to

```
example.com/show?id_item=999
```

To disallow from id_item 1 to 500.
It´s possible to disallow in robots.txt a range "id_item" without write tons (500 in that case) of lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is really no way to do this with robots.txt, other than having 500 lines, one for each number. (**not** a recommendation!) The closest thing is the wildcard extension "*", but this will match a string of any length, made up of any characters. There is no way to match a specific pattern of digits, which is what you would need to match a numeric range.

If your goal is to keep these pages out of the search engines, then the best way to do this is to add code to selectively block these pages with [robots meta tags or x-robots-tag headers](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag) whenever the id is in the target range.

If your goal is to prevent the pages from being crawled at all (e.g. to reduce server load) then you are out of luck. You will have to choose between blocking all of them (with `Disallow: /show?id_item=`) or none of them.

Comment: As I can read in https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt?hl=en "A maximum file size may be enforced per crawler. Content which is after the maximum file size may be ignored. Google currently enforces a size limit of 500 kilobytes (KB).". Why it´s not recommended a robots.txt of 500 lines?

Comment: I mostly just recommend against it because it will turn your robots.txt file into an ugly, hard-to-maintain mess. This (IMHO) is a bad idea, because it makes it much too easy to miss future problems that can do serious harm to your site.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the range. It’s easy for your example (1 to 999, disallowing 1 to 500):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /show?id_item=1
Disallow: /show?id_item=2
Disallow: /show?id_item=3
Disallow: /show?id_item=4
Disallow: /show?id_item=500
```

This disallows any *id_item* that **starts with** "1", "2", "3", "4", or "500".

So URLs like these will be disallowed:

```
https://example.com/show?id_item=1
https://example.com/show?id_item=19
https://example.com/show?id_item=150
https://example.com/show?id_item=1350
https://example.com/show?id_item=1foo
```

If you expect IDs higher than 999, it doesn’t work like that anymore (because IDs like "1001" would also be disallowed). You might have to make use of `Allow` then (but this feature isn’t part of the original robots.txt spec, so not necessarily supported by all consumers), and the list becomes longer.

Depending on the range, `$` might be useful. It indicates the end of the URL (but this is also a feature that’s not part of the original robots.txt spec, so it’s not necessarily supported by all robots.txt parsers). For example, the following line would only block ID "500":

```
Disallow: /show?id_item=500$
```